# About listviews in C#

Tags: c#, listview

i am getting string from user and i need to print this string to screen using listview. but my code not working. whats my wrong

```
        string tagToSearch = null;
        tagToSearch = textBoxSearch.Text;

        ListViewItem lvItem = new ListViewItem(tagToSearch);
        listViewSearch.Items.Insert(0, lvItem);

        listViewSearch.Refresh();
```

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/140505)

Comment: i can take the text from textbox. but i cant write it to listview

Comment: The code you wrote works. How is the ListView displayed? Are you using any thumbnails or columns?

Comment: i am using columns. when i use thumbnails i can print it out. but when i use columbs it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the ListView to show something in Details mode you have to add at least [one column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.columns.aspx).

```
// Create columns for the items and subitems.
// Width of -2 indicates auto-size.
listView1.Columns.Add("Item Column", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
```

Answer (score 0):

To add your item to the ListView you should use listViewSearch.Items.Add(lvItem);

Comment: Thank you a lot. i did it by changing View of list from details to list in visual studio 8.